# dynamic type casting?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class

```
A<T> {
    T value;
    public T getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(T value) { this.value = value;}
}
```

And try to use it with non-generic method like this:

```
A<?>[] as = new A<?>[2]; as[0] = new A<Integer>(); as[1] = new A<String>();
for(A<?> a : as) {
    someobj.put(a.getValue()); // <-- got an error "The method put(String) is not applicable for the arguments (capture#2-of ?)"
}
```

someobj has put(String s), put(Integer i) etc.

How can i do something like dynamic type casting and fix an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Marko, the type of your generic A is lost. But what you could do is to use reflection to invoke the *correct* "put" method.

Something like this:

```
A<?>[] as = new A<?>[2]; as[0] = new A<Integer>(); as[1] = new A<String>();
for(A<?> a : as) {
    Method m = someobj.getClass().getMethod("put", a.getValue().getClass());
    m.invoke(somobj, a.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The information you provided at instantiation of A gets lost as soon as you put those in the array of `A<?>`. Generics are only visible to the compiler.

You are basically trying to call `someobj.put(Object o)` -- and that doesn't exist. You must downcast to the type of argument you wish to call. There is no dynamic dispatch done on the arguments of the method, only on the object it is called upon. The compiler must choose exactly which method will be used -- put(String) or put(Object). That cannot be decided at runtime.

Theoretically, if you really wanted to do dynamic dispatch in your scenario, you'd be forced to used the Visitor pattern. I wouldn't recommend it, it's very cumbersome.